# JSONP - WebApi EntitySetController

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, jsonp, odata

I have a web api project, and have added a JSONP formatter, and tested it works fine using the standard WebApi implementation. I also need to expose oData - however JSONP formatter seems to be ignored for oData controller using EntitySetController?

```
public class LogsController : EntitySetController<Log, int>
{
    // other code here...

   [Queryable(PageSize = 50,MaxTop = 100)]
    public override IQueryable<Log> Get()
    {
        return entities.Logs;
    }

    protected override Log GetEntityByKey(int key)
    {
        return entities.Logs.FirstOrDefault(p => p.id == key);
    }
}


public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );

        ODataModelBuilder modelBuilder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        modelBuilder.EntitySet<Log>("Logs");

        Microsoft.Data.Edm.IEdmModel model = modelBuilder.GetEdmModel();
        config.Routes.MapODataRoute("ODataRoute", "odata", model);
    }

public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
           FormatterConfig.RegisterFormatters(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.Formatters);
    }
}

public class FormatterConfig
{
    public static void RegisterFormatters(MediaTypeFormatterCollection formatters)
    {
        var jsonFormatter = formatters.JsonFormatter;
        jsonFormatter.SerializerSettings = new JsonSerializerSettings
        {
            ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
        };

        // Insert the JSONP formatter in front of the standard JSON formatter.
        var jsonpFormatter = new JsonpMediaTypeFormatter(formatters.JsonFormatter);
        formatters.Insert(0, jsonpFormatter);


    }
}
```

How can I use EntitySetController with JSONP?

Sample URL:

```
GET http://example.com/odata/Logs?$orderby=id%20desc&$top=100&callback=jQuery19106219180973712355_1380508978486&_=1380508978487 HTTP/1.1
```

Comment: have you found the solution for your problem?

Answer (score 1):

EntitySetController replaces the formatters with specialized OData formatters  -- that's how it can return OData format.

EDIT: OData defines a particular format for responses, which is why EntitySetController replaces the default formatters with OData formatters.

Potentially you could override the default OData formatters to support JSONP. You would need to derive from **System.Web.Http.OData.Formatter.ODataMediaTypeFormatter**. If you put ODataMediaTypeFormatter instances into the formatters collection, then EntitySetController will not replace them.

Also: Is it possible for your app to use CORS rather than JSONP?

Comment: And how does this help us to use EntitySetController with JSONP?

Comment: You would need to extend the OData formatters to support JSONP.

Answer (score 0):

How to return json format from entitysetcontroller? 
Firstly, you should use odatalib(5.6.0) from nuget. 
And add this code to client code

```
container.Format.UseJson();
```